# How can slightly elliptically polarized light pass through a polarizer set to pass linearly polarized light?

Tags: optics, polarization

How can slightly elliptically polarized light pass through a polarizer set to pass linearly polarized light? And what will be the corresponding change in intensity?

Comment: Help us out: why do you think it would not pass?

Comment: Well, I thought it wouldn't pass because the polarizer would block all polarizations except linear, and since the incoming beam is elliptical (slight or not) it wouldn't go through. I've seen that the output intensity in this case is given by $I=I_{0} sin^{2} (\phi /2)$ where $\phi$ is the phase shift, but I don't understand how that is obtained.

Comment: So it would seem that your confusion lies in understanding linear vs elliptical vs circular polarization?

Answer (score 1):

Think of any polarization as the vector sum of a horizontal and a vertical linear polarization that may or may not have different amplitudes or phase shifts. If both the horizontal and the vertical components have equal amplitudes and are in phase you end up with a linearly polarized wave which has a polarization angle of 45 degrees. If the horizontal and vertical components have equal amplitudes but are out of phase by a quarter-cycle the vector sum has constant norm, but rotates tracing out a circle (i.e. circular polarization). If the horizontal and vertical components are out of phase by anything other than an integer multiple of quarter-cycles the vector sum will trace out an ellipse instead of a circle (i.e. elliptical polarization). By choise of coordinate system the elliptical polarization can also be described with the two components being out of phase by a quarter-cycle but having different amplitudes. Nonetheless elliptically polarized light already contains a small portion of light polarized in any direction just because the vector sum traces out a full rotation. Therefore if you shine elliptically polarized light through a linear polarization filter, the projection of the vector sum of horizontal and vertical polarization onto the filter direction will be oscillating. And that will be the light that gets through your filter.

I don't know what your phase shift refers to. Is it the shift between the horizontal and vertical component or the angle between the filter direction and one of the coordinate axes of the polarized light? I guess both might be needed to calculate the intensity of the light shining through. It should be a fairly straight forward calculation when the right sketches have been drawn (assuming you are familliar with vector projection).